# How to print multidimensional array using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have array in PHP that is getting saved to `$_SESSION`. I want to output the array in proper readable format and in table form.

I tried checking array contents as `print_r($_SESSION['post-data'])` and output is as

```
Array ( [jcart_item_name] => Array ( [0] => Choley Bhature [1] => Onion Kulcha with 
Chana and Raita [2] => Dal Makhani ) [jcart_item_id] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 
5 [2] => 6 ) [jcart_item_price] =>Array ( [0] => 85 [1] => 90 [2] => 105 ) 
[jcart_item_qty] => Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 1 [2] => 1[jcart_checkout] => PlaceOrder)
```

I want to output only `jcart_item_name`, `jcart_item_qty` and `jcart_item_price` in below format

```
Item Name       Item Qty    Item Price
--------------------------------------
Choley Bhature     3          50
```

Comment: pro tip: use the <pre> tag when printing/dumping objects and arrays to have them pretty printed :)

Comment: $array['jcart_item_name'][0]; $array['jcart_item_name'][0] ;$array['jcart_item_qty'][0]; and so on.. in a loop

Comment: loop is the thing i want to know... the way u told already tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to divide this array into several arrays, for example: jcart_item_name, jcart_item_qty and jcart_item_price are three array. Then as your arrays have the same size, you can use the function `count()` or `sizeof()` to get the size. Then you will get:
    //Now we have those three arrays
    $arr1; //jcart_item_name array
    $arr2; //jcart_item_qty array
    $arr3; //jcart_item_price array

```
$size = sizeof($arr1); //all arrays size is the same


for ($i=0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    //DO WHAT YOU WANT
    echo $arr1[$i]."<br>";
    echo $arr2[$i]."<br>";
    echo $arr3[$i]."<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds yummy...
Does your array need to be associative?

```
<?php
$myArray = Array (
Array ( 1, 5, 6),
Array ('Choley Bhature', 'Onion Kulcha with Chana and Raita', 'Dal Makhani'),
Array (3, 1, 1),
Array (85, 90, 105));

echo "<table><tr><td>Id</td><td>Item Name</td><td>Qty.</td><td>Price</td></tr><br/>";
    for ($j=0; $j<count($myArray[0]); $j++){
        echo "<tr><td>".$myArray[0][$j]."</td><td>".$myArray[1][$j]."</td><td>".$myArray[2][$j]."</td><td>".$myArray[3][$j]."</td>";
    }
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can do the formatting yourself, but this is how you get the values you want...

```
foreach($_SESSION['jcart_item_name'] as $key => $item) {

    echo $item . ' - ' . $_SESSION['jcart_item_qty'][$key] . ' - ' . $_SESSION['jcart_item_price'][$key] . '<br>';

}
```

I would suggest structuring your array differently tho... something like this

```
$_SESSION['jcart_items'] = array(
     array('name' => 'Choley Bhature', 'price' => 85, 'qty' => 3),
     array('name' => 'Onion Kulcha with Chana and Raita', 'price' => 90, 'qty' => 1)
     ...etc
);
```

That way for can do a simple foreach loop on $_SESSION['jcart_items'] and it's more readable

```
foreach($_SESSION['jcart_items'] as $k => $item) {
    echo $item['name'] . ' - ' . $item ['qty'] . ' - ' . $item['price'] . '<br>';
}
```